# Adding a Time Stamp to an RSS Feed

Tags: html, xml, rss

I am interested in learning more about how to use RSS feeds.

For instance, here is a query I am using on an RSS Feed to find out all articles:

- Containing the term "iphone"
- In the English language
- Published in Canada
- Before: 2009-02-09
- After:2009-01-08

Here is the query: https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=iphone%20+after:2009-01-08+before:2009-02-09&hl=en-CA&gl=CA&ceid=CA:en

The result of this query takes me to the following XML page:

[image]

**My Question:** I am interested in specifying time stamps this query (e.g. 15:43:21 i.e. 3:43 PM) - is it possible to include this information in the query/

I notice that in the resulting XML, the following field is available that contains information on time:

```
<pubDate>Fri, 09 Jan 2009 08:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
```

**Is it possible to add this to the query?**

Thanks!

Comment: I may be wrong (and I'll be happy to be proven so...) but I don't think this one is possible to do through the query. One possible workaround is this: the resulting rss feed is in xml format. You can parse the xml response with an xml parser (for example, in Python you would use lxml; it can be done in other languages, including xquery), then using xpath you can find all the `<item>`s with a `<pubDate>` child, which (once processed) meets your timestamp requirement. At that point, you can copy the target `<item>` to another file, delete all the non-conforming `<item>`s, etc.