# Including Titles in HTML Requests

Tags: html, xml, rss

**I am interested in learning how to use RSS Feeds to find older versions of webpages on Google.**

I know that this possible using websites such as WayBackMachine (https://archive.org/web/) and some websites themselves include historical archived versions - but I am interested in learning how to do this with RSS Feeds

For example, here is a website: https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#maps_new-admissions-rate-county

When I look at the HTML source for this website, I observe the following:

For instance, here is an RSS request :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="“Pragma”" content="”no-cache”" />
        <meta http-equiv="“Expires”" content="”-1″" />
        <meta http-equiv="“CACHE-CONTROL”" content="”NO-CACHE”" />
        <meta name="description" content="CDC’s home for COVID-19 data. Visualizations, graphs, and data in one easy-to-use website." />
        <meta property="og:title" content="COVID Data Tracker" />
```

**My Question:** Suppose I want to locate a version of this website on the Google RSS feed between two specific dates - I tried to write the following query based on "title" of this website (i.e. I only want to return websites that contain these 3 words in the TITLE):

https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=COVID%20AND%20DATA%20AND%20TRACKER++after:2022-01-08+before:2022-01-09&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en

**However, the results of this query are not returning websites based on the "title"**, e.g.:

```
<item>
<title>Hong Kong may consider tracking function on ‘Leave Home Safe’ app: health chief - South China Morning Post</title>
<link>https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMid2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnNjbXAuY29tL25ld3MvaG9uZy1rb25nL2hlYWx0aC1lbnZpcm9ubWVudC9hcnRpY2xlLzMxNjI2NDcvY29yb25hdmlydXMtaG9uZy1rb25nLW1heS1yZXNvcnQtaG9tZS1xdWFyYW50aW5l0gF3aHR0cHM6Ly9hbXAuc2NtcC5jb20vbmV3cy9ob25nLWtvbmcvaGVhbHRoLWVudmlyb25tZW50L2FydGljbGUvMzE2MjY0Ny9jb3JvbmF2aXJ1cy1ob25nLWtvbmctbWF5LXJlc29ydC1ob21lLXF1YXJhbnRpbmU?oc=5</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">CBMid2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnNjbXAuY29tL25ld3MvaG9uZy1rb25nL2hlYWx0aC1lbnZpcm9ubWVudC9hcnRpY2xlLzMxNjI2NDcvY29yb25hdmlydXMtaG9uZy1rb25nLW1heS1yZXNvcnQtaG9tZS1xdWFyYW50aW5l0gF3aHR0cHM6Ly9hbXAuc2NtcC5jb20vbmV3cy9ob25nLWtvbmcvaGVhbHRoLWVudmlyb25tZW50L2FydGljbGUvMzE2MjY0Ny9jb3JvbmF2aXJ1cy1ob25nLWtvbmctbWF5LXJlc29ydC1ob21lLXF1YXJhbnRpbmU</guid>
<pubDate>Sat, 08 Jan 2022 08:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<description><a href="https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMid2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnNjbXAuY29tL25ld3MvaG9uZy1rb25nL2hlYWx0aC1lbnZpcm9ubWVudC9hcnRpY2xlLzMxNjI2NDcvY29yb25hdmlydXMtaG9uZy1rb25nLW1heS1yZXNvcnQtaG9tZS1xdWFyYW50aW5l0gF3aHR0cHM6Ly9hbXAuc2NtcC5jb20vbmV3cy9ob25nLWtvbmcvaGVhbHRoLWVudmlyb25tZW50L2FydGljbGUvMzE2MjY0Ny9jb3JvbmF2aXJ1cy1ob25nLWtvbmctbWF5LXJlc29ydC1ob21lLXF1YXJhbnRpbmU?oc=5" target="_blank">Hong Kong may consider tracking function on ‘Leave Home Safe’ app: health chief</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">South China Morning Post</font></description>
<source url="https://www.scmp.com">South China Morning Post</source>
</item>
```

**I only want to return results that contain all 3 search terms in the title.**

Can something be done to change this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing you search to

```
https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=allintitle:TRACKER%20DATA%20COVID++after:2020-01-08+before:2022-01-09&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en
```

Note that I changed the start year to 2020 since nothing met your requirements with your original start date.

Comment: @ jack fleeting: thank you so much for your answer! is it possible to include information about the "source url" in the query request?

Comment: I have created another question in case you are interested in answering there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592055/adding-source-urls-in-html-requests

Comment: Is it possible to search by time stramps? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585958/adding-a-time-stamp-to-an-rss-feed

Comment: @stats_noob I'll take a look at the other question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am currently trying different combinations to see if time stamps can be added to the dates..